# livewire - set default option on a select field

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a select element like this:

```
<select wire:model="state" >
    <option value="">Choose a State:</option>
    @foreach($state_list as $abbr=>$state)
        <option >{{$state}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

I'd like to have a default state that shows to the user.  I've tried setting the $state property directly, and through the mount() method, and by using the SELECT attribute in the option.

As someone pointed out, I didn't have a value field.  Additionally, in the actual code, this was a key on a property, so the field was actually name="bank[state]", so I had to add the state property in mount(), like this:

```
public function mount() {
    $us_state_properties = ['address', 'bank'];
    foreach($us_state_properties as $add) {
        $this->{$add.".state"} = "Florida";
    }
    foreach($this->multi_us_state_properties as $add) {
        $this->{$add.".0.state"} = "Florida";
    }
}
```

And some fields were dynamically added within the form, as you can see in the second foreach loop.

Comment: is your default state the first item of the array? or do you mean to have a `Choose a state` kind of default value

Comment: @Abdusalammohamed "choose a state" is the first option; under certain circumstances, the default should be "FL" instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you forget the `value` in
`<option value="{{$state}}">{{$state}}</option>`

```html
<select wire:model="state" >
    <option value="">Choose a State:</option>
    @foreach($state_list as $abbr=>$state)
        <option value="{{$state}}">{{$state}}</option> <!-- this -->
        <!-- <option value="{{$abbr}}">{{$state}}</option> --> <!-- or this ? -->
    @endforeach
</select>
```

try to force test it

```
class FormSelectOption extends Component
{
    public $state = 'FL';

    ...
}
```

Reference: https://laravel-livewire.com/screencasts/form-selects